# evaluating if a string "nearly" matches another

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Is there a way in psql to find out if a string is nearly the same as another?

For example:   "This sting, on screen" nearly matches "This String, on scren"

Comment: You could try the functions provided by the extension [fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `levenshtein` function

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;

select levenshtein('This sting, on screen'::text, 'This String, on scren'::text); 
-- returns 3
select levenshtein('A very diferent texto'::text, 'of other kind of words'::text); 
-- returns 18
```

Look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/fuzzystrmatch.html